# RecyclerView partially recycling some views

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-recyclerview

I have an app which displays the **Matchday** of some soccer competitions depending **date** of the match. I am using a spinner to **re-create** the adapter of my RecyclerView depending on the User selection with some *dummyData()*. But sometimes while the RecyclerView is first initialized or recycled it displays literally the format of my **.xml**.

I managed to reduce the level of visual glitch by adding a custom animation on the Adapter but still sometimes it just happens, like 10% of the time I change **Matchday**.

**format_home.xml**

This is the placeholder I created to design this format.

[image: format_home.xml]

**Gif showing problem:**

[image: problem]

**HomeFragment.java**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.home_recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

    mSpinner = view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_home);


    List<String> matchDay = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        matchDay.add("Matchday " + (i + 1));
    }
    HomeSpinnerAdapter dataAdapter = new HomeSpinnerAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.format_home_spinner, matchDay);
    mSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            mHomeItems = new ArrayList<>();
            mDisposable.add(Observable.fromArray(mHomeItems)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(homeItems -> {

                        Map<String, List<Matchday>> hashMap = toMap(dummyData());

                        // Map Key
                        for (String date : hashMap.keySet()) {
                            Header header = new Header(date);
                            homeItems.add(header);
                            for (Matchday matchday : hashMap.get(date)) {
                                MatchItem matchItem = new MatchItem(matchday);
                                homeItems.add(matchItem);
                            }
                        }
                        mAdapter = new HomeAdapter(homeItems, getActivity(), mTeamViewModel);
                        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                    }));

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

    return view;
}
 // Map Value List<T>
private Map<String,List<Matchday>> toMap(List<Matchday> matchdays) {
    Map<String, List<Matchday>> map = new TreeMap<>();
    for (Matchday matchday : matchdays){
        List<Matchday> value = map.get(matchday.getDate());
        if (value == null) {
            value = new ArrayList<>();
            map.put(matchday.getDate(), value);
        }
        value.add(matchday);
    }
    return map;
}


public List<Matchday> dummyData(){
    mMatchdayList = new ArrayList<>();
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i ++){
        mMatchdayList.add(new Matchday((i+1), buildRandomDateInCurrentMonth(), 1, random.nextInt(36), 0, 0, random.nextInt(36)));
    }
    return mMatchdayList;
}
```

If you have any feedback or need any other activity, let me know! TY

Comment: Create the `RecyclerView` adapter before the `onClick` and then call `notifyDatasetChanged()` in the `onItemSelected()`

Comment: Hi, still happening. :|

Comment: @Ispam Depends if you have enabled `setStableIds` in your HomeAdapter class. If yes, check the method `getItemId` (I think), what is the logic of every unique id for every row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @jantursky and some deep digging in the web I came across this series of [articles](https://android.jlelse.eu/anatomy-of-recyclerview-part-1-a-search-for-a-viewholder-404ba3453714) and managed to identify that my **RecyclerView** was recreating all views in the absence of `setStableIds(true)` because in recyclers Scrap lists are the first place where the RecyclerView looks when searching for a ViewHolder.

**So to resolve the problem:**

- Created an interface to retrieve List **IDS**.
- Created a *refreshAdapter()* method in the **Adapter**.
- Initialized and instantiate the **Adapter** outside the ` mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener() with *setHasStableIds(**true**)*.
- Inside the `mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener`call *refreshAdapter()*